# Is there a way to ignore "TypeError - 0 positional arguments but 1 was given"?

Tags: python, callback, typeerror

I understand why this is happening, because callback doesn't take any arguments, but I'm passing one in `x`.
But is there a stop this error from happening? i'm making an event manager, and sometimes you don't always need the extra information that is passed through the parameters.

```
import time

callbacks = {
    "on_foo": []
}

def callback_register(name, callback, *args, **kwargs):
    def cb(*args, **kwargs):
        return callback(*args, **kwargs)
    callbacks[name].append(cb)

def callback_unregister(name):
    del callbacks[name]

def callback_exists(name):
    return name in callbacks

def callback_call(name, *args, **kwargs):
    for cb in callbacks[name]:
        cb(*args, **kwargs)

def foo():
    print("FOO!")
    called_at = time.time()
    callback_call("on_foo", called_at)

callback_register("on_foo", lambda x: print(f"foo was called at {x}"))

callback_register("on_foo", lambda: print(f"foo has been called!")) #errors 
# no need for the called_at variable since it's not being used in this callback

foo()
```

I have solved my answer and would like to post an answer.

Comment: declare it as `callback(x=None)`

Comment: There must be a defined interface about what arguments callbacks must expect and accept. If that callback doesn’t want that argument, it is free to ignore it; but accept it it must.

Comment: I've edited it more to fit my problem more realistically, @LeiYang

Comment: so why do you pass x?

Comment: @LeiYang edited again..

Answer (score 0):

Like a regular function in Python, which can take variable number of arguments using ***args** , you could add ***args** to lambda arguments.

```
callback = lambda *args: print(5)
```

Edit: This question was abruptly changed. So updated answer:

```
lambda *args: print(f"foo has been called!")
```

Comment: I could.. yeah, but if I don't need to use the variable then I don't want to add any args. check the example

Comment: A parameter is being passed to the lambda irrespective of usage. Even if it is not being used, *args would let the lambda execute even if n number of arguments are passed at run time.

Comment: If you explicitly want to ignore the parameter, you should name it `*_`.